# How to avoid import class and implement protocol?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

One ViewController class already imported the UIView class into it. 
Now when implementing the protocol into same class.

Here @protocol class in already imported WeeklyView Class.

Now in Weekly View I got scenario to implement the @protocol method.
So i need import PlanViewController into there.

It looks like classA import ClassB and ClassB import ClassA that is wrong.

How to avoid this behaviour in this case? and implement the protocol.

// ViewController class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WeeklyView.h"
@protocol PlanViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)nextWeekGlanceCategory :(NSString *)startweekDate endWeekDate:(NSString *)endWeekDate;
@end
```

// Another class Weeklyview

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PlanViewController.h"
@interface WeeklyView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,PlanViewControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: Well my suggestion will be putting the protocol to a different headerFile. Second solution will be importing planViewController on the implementation file. then on the header file you call @protocol PlanViewControllerDelegate, this will still work. third have the implementation file contain the interface category of somesort then do the assigning of the delegate there

Answer (score 1):

Just put your protocol in **separate** header file.

To create protocol header file you can pick it like this:
File->New->Objective-c File->Protocol.